# SwaggerUi does not take the data from the yml file

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am new to the world of Swagger, trying to implement it for my own application. My problem is that SwaggerUi doesn't take my swagger.yml file but takes it into controller. In fact, I have problems with authentication.

**Swagger.yml**

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "1.1"
  title:  ABC Operations
  termsOfService: http://swagger.io/terms/
host: <HOST>
basePath: /abc/operations
tags:
- name: Stored Message
  description: Stored Message Operations
schemes:
- http
- https
security:
  - basic_auth: []
paths:
  /stored-message/{transactionId}:
    get:
      tags:
      - Stored Message
      summary: Stored Message Retrieval by TransactionId
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - in: path
        name: transactionId
        required: true
        type: string
           
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
        404:
          description: Not Found
        500:
          description: Internal Server Error

    put:
      tags:
      - Stored Message
      summary: Stored Message Update
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - in: path
        name: transactionId
        required: true
        type: string
      - in: body
        name: Modified Stored Message
        schema:
         type: object
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
        404:
          description: Not Found
        500:
          description: Internal Server Error
  
securityDefinitions:
  basic_auth:
    type: basic
externalDocs:
  description: Find out more about Swagger
  url: http://swagger.io
```

In fact in the SwaggerUi part it does not fill in the new field by default.
How can I make swagger Ui fetch data from swagger.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "application.property" file you have to add this string

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.url: /yourfilename.yml
```

of and specify the yml file you want to use to start the swaggerUi.

The file must be inside **src-> resource->static** to be viewed. I recommend that you see the official documentation on the Springdoc website https://springdoc.org/faq.html.

Good day